# Bootloader install failed - RAID

Tags: installation, 13.04, grub2, raid, bootloader

I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 on a desktop with hardware raid (3 disks in raid 5). I believe I have an ICH8 chipset, if that is relevant.

So, I created an install USB stick with Startup Disk Creator with the amd64 Ubuntu Desktop image. I proceed through the install, select to erase everything and install Ubuntu (no lvm, no encryption, or anything like that). The install seems to go fine, until the very end, I get an Error that says "Failed to install GRUB"

Unable to install GRUB in

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZfOu.png]

I think it initially tried /dev/sda, but then I got a menu where I could select a net partition. I tried other selections, but nothing seemed to work. Do I need to unmount something to install GRUB?

Screenshot with other install path candidates:

Bootloader install failed

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLXzj.png]

Here is the output of `ls -l /dev/mapper`

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -l /dev/mapper
total 0
crw------- 1 root root  10, 236 Aug 25 06:48 control
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252,   0 Aug 25 14:17 isw_bifaeaafcc_Volume0
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252,   1 Aug 25 14:17 isw_bifaeaafcc_Volume0p1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252,   2 Aug 25 14:17 isw_bifaeaafcc_Volume0p2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252,   3 Aug 25 14:17 isw_bifaeaafcc_Volume0p5
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

I eventually selected "Continue without a bootloader." in hopes that I can figure out how to install GRUB post-install.

Any ideas on getting GRUB installed, so this system will boot? Please let me know if you need any further details or system specs.

EDIT: Here is the output from /var/log/syslog during the failure

```
Aug 25 23:03:50 ubuntu grub-installer: info: architecture: amd64/generic
Aug 25 23:03:50 ubuntu grub-installer: info: Mounting /proc into /target
Aug 25 23:03:50 ubuntu ubiquity: grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of /dev/mapper/isw_bifaeaafcc_Volume0p1.
Aug 25 23:03:51 ubuntu ubiquity: grub-probe: error:
Aug 25 23:03:51 ubuntu ubiquity:  
Aug 25 23:03:51 ubuntu ubiquity: failed to get canonical path of /dev/mapper/isw_bifaeaafcc_Volume0p1
Aug 25 23:03:51 ubuntu ubiquity: .
Aug 25 23:03:51 ubuntu ubiquity: File descriptor 3 (pipe:[140038]) leaked on lvdisplay invocation.
Aug 25 23:03:51 ubuntu ubiquity:  Parent PID 17588: /bin/sh
Aug 25 23:03:51 ubuntu ubiquity:   
Aug 25 23:03:51 ubuntu ubiquity: Volume group "isw_bifaeaafcc_Volume0p1" not found
Aug 25 23:03:51 ubuntu ubiquity: 
Aug 25 23:03:51 ubuntu ubiquity:   
Aug 25 23:03:51 ubuntu ubiquity: Skipping volume group isw_bifaeaafcc_Volume0p1
Aug 25 23:03:51 ubuntu ubiquity: 
Aug 25 23:03:51 ubuntu grub-installer: info: Identified partition label for /dev/mapper/isw_bifaeaafcc_Volume0p1: loop
Aug 25 23:03:52 ubuntu grub-installer: dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove grub which isn't installed
Aug 25 23:03:52 ubuntu grub-installer: dpGkg: warning: ignoring request to remove grub-legacy which isn't installed
Aug 25 23:03:52 ubuntu grub-installer: dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove grub-efi which isn't installed
Aug 25 23:03:52 ubuntu grub-installer: dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove grub-efi-amd64-bin which isn't installed
Aug 25 23:03:52 ubuntu grub-installer: dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove grub-efi-amd64 which isn't installed
Aug 25 23:03:52 ubuntu grub-installer: dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove grub-efi-amd64-signed which isn't installed
Aug 25 23:03:52 ubuntu grub-installer: dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove grub-efi-ia32-bin which isn't installed
Aug 25 23:03:52 ubuntu grub-installer: dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove grub-efi-ia32 which isn't installed
Aug 25 23:03:53 ubuntu grub-installer: info: Installing grub on '/dev/mapper/isw_bifaeaafcc_Volume0p1'
Aug 25 23:03:53 ubuntu grub-installer: info: grub-install does not support --no-floppy
Aug 25 23:03:53 ubuntu grub-installer: info: Running chroot /target grub-install  --force "/dev/mapper/isw_bifaeaafcc_Volume0p1"
Aug 25 23:03:54 ubuntu grub-installer: Path `/boot/grub' is not readable by GRUB on boot. Installation is impossible. Aborting.
Aug 25 23:03:54 ubuntu grub-installer: error: Running 'grub-install  --force "/dev/mapper/isw_bifaeaafcc_Volume0p1"' failed.
```

Comment: What does `sudo grub-probe -t fs -vvd /dev/mapper/isw_bifaeaafcc_Volume0p1` show?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [fake raid](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/FakeRaidHowto) controller.  Unless you must dual boot with Windows, it is best to avoid their use and stick with plain old Linux software raid, which you can set up using the alternate installer after destroying the fake raid array in the bios utility.

If you must use the fake raid, to troubleshoot the failure further you will need to check /var/log/syslog for more detailed error messages on why grub-install failed.

Comment: I would like to just use the fake raid, in case I ever need to mount the filesystem from a bootable USB stick. I edited my post with log output.